# ElasticSearch with multiple filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a query that will find all user documents `(docType = user)` and then filter them based on many filters. Such as location, gender, age, etc. The filters are added / removed based on user input on the search function I'm building.

Below returns no results:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                    "and": {
                        "filters": 
                        [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "doc.docType": "user"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "doc.data.profile.location" : "CA"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Below return results:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "field": {
                    "doc.data.profile.location" : "CA"
                }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "and": {
                        "filters": 
                        [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "doc.docType": "user"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The latter, although returning results, isn't going to work in the long run as I may want to include an extra filter for age, gender, etc and I can't seem to add multiple fields.  The first query works if I remove the filter for location.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: exactly what I needed. Worked a charm!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The bool filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html#query-dsl-bool-filter) allows you to chain multiple `MUST`, `SHOULD` and `SHOULD_NOT` requests together. Allowing for you to construct this into one query.

Comment: Thank you. I will do more research and mark your answer as accepted soon if it turns out to be what I need :)

Comment: The bool filter is now replaced  by the Bool Query : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 14):

Here is how you can write multiple filter query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term" : {
            "id":254
          }
        },
        {
          "term" : {
            "cityId":35
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

That way you can chain multiple musts together to get the desired result.